# Refactoring permutation finding

Tags: java, refactoring

I try to refactor this code for some hours.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int ii = 2; ii <= 10; ii++) {
            if (ii > i) {
                for (int iii = 3; iii <= 10; iii++) {
                    if (iii > ii && iii > i) {
                        for (int iiii = 4; iiii <= 10; iiii++) {
                            if (iiii > i && iiii > ii && iiii > iii) {
                                for (int iiiii = 5; iiiii <= 10; iiiii++) {
                                    if (iiiii > i && iiiii > ii && iiiii > iii && iiiii > iiii) {
                                        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, i + " " + ii + " " + iii + " " + iiii + " " + iiiii + "\n", true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The goal will be to get two input integers( the number of the loops (5 in this code), and the max value of a number (10 in this case), but i have no ide how to make that happen. Sorry for my not perfect english. Will be a big help for my homework.

Comment: it's a lot of i's :-)

Comment: I think that code is beautiful as is!

Comment: It appears to be a 5 digit decimal number you're after, where each digit is large than the one before.

Comment: At the very least you can get rid of all `if` statements by adjusting the starting point of your loops.

Comment: Love these kinds of homework questions... because this *totally* happens in real life. /s

Comment: You need an array for all the different `i...` numbers, a single loop, and some logic to tell you which array entry to increment.

Comment: Thanks :)
The goal will be to write all possible arrays where the user can input how mutch numbers, and what is the biggest number. I know my english sucks...Its just hard to describle even in my own language.

Comment: Your English is fine.  I think we all understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a variable number of loops you need to use recursion. Something like this.

```
public static void combine(int values, int maximum, Consumer<int[]> consumer) {
    combine0(0, values, 1, maximum-values+1, new int[values], consumer);
}

static void consumer0(int index, int values, int min, int max, List<Integer> ints, Consumer<List<integer>> consumer) {
    if (index == values) {
        consumer.apply(ints);
        return;
    }
    for(int i = min; i <= max ; i ++) {
        ints[index] = i;
        comsumer0(index+1, values, min+1, max+1, ints, consumer);
    }
}
```

---

There is lots of ways to improve it, You could use just one loop, but you would have to use some maths ;)

I would start with.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    for (int ii = 2; ii <= 10; ii++) {
        if (ii > i) {
```

Is the same as

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int ii = i+1; ii <= 10; ii++) {
```

As you add more loops you can see that `i` can't ever be 10, or 9 etc in the same way you could see that `ii` had to be at least 2.

Comment: Thank you, I like your way thinking about the problem.
Can you help with the math or organizing the loop part. I just cant get my head around it. Would be mutch easier to understand if I actualy see some example and from that "aha moment" I can figure out some abstract way to do it next time.

Comment: @digitalized Each time the method calls itself you get another nested loop.

Comment: No, you really don't need to use recursion at all.  I don't think this is the simplest approach to the problem.  See my comment where I describe how to do it.  Maybe I should turn it into an answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace you could be right, would need to see your solution.